# Five gallon fish tank

Tags: fish

I have a ailing Betta. The man at the aquarium store sold me some meds for fungus. I think it burnt him. Now he has fin rot. Today I took out about a gallon of water and put in fresh with Prime conditioner and a bit of aqua salt. Also added Melafix per instructions. Poor thing is almost fin less, but still swimming.

Now my question is, if he pulls through I will be very happy, but if he dies, what can I do about getting the tank sanitized? I read where people use bleach water, that's a no no. Acrylic tank, I used to use salt to scrub with, but don't know if this will scratch it and I would boil rocks. What about all the plants? and the decorations? This tank cost me a lot of money setting it up and would like to be able to re use it in the future, if my little buddy does not make it. I am afraid I will transfer this disease to another fish. Opinions any one?

I am so shocked this even happened. I had many tanks before and as well as Betas, hardly lost any fish, just started back to this hobby and this happened.

Comment: What's wrong with using bleach? It's safe and it evaporates or can be neutralized without risking leaving any trace of it in the tank.

Comment: Bleach is not even good for humans.It is a cancer causing agent but no one will tell you that. I would hate to have resadue in my tank. It clings to cracks and crevases of decorations. Sorry Jestep it never goes away. If you use it in your cloths just smell, isn't that sent of bleach wonderful? To rhis day my Beta is still alive and trying to swim. Poor baby looks like a Goodyear blimp. Now I just have to get him to start eating again. I try giving him mini pellets and blood worms. He'll put one in his mouth then spits it out. Do not see any mouth fungus

Comment: I have to disagree with your opinion on bleach. Under normal household use, aquariums as well, it's one of the safest ways to disinfect your equipment. If you want to get technical, melafix contains known carcinogens, and your tap water likely does as well.

Comment: Berfore you give advice Jestep, please google the product you are  talking about. Melafix is an all natural medication. It's used for fin rot and other ailments to a fish. It helps re generate fins, while soothing them. I would under no surcamstance use bleach of any kind to clean any part of my aquariums. I always used salt and hot water. Another thing to use for a sick fish is aqua salt. Now with the salt and Melafix he is swiming like crazy, even though he still resembles a Good Year blimp, responding to me, eating and re generating scales and fins. I was told a long time ago no bleach

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could try one of two things. Either hydrogen peroxide, which is a much milder alternative to bleach and cleans as well as bleach (it just degraded in sunlight so is harder to store); or use the powdered oxygen they use to clean carboys and the equipment when making wine or beer. It should be safe.